# R - Read excel into a dataframe in the source structure and get the count of rows read

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to read excel into a dataframe using  R.

```
dat = lapply(file.list, function(i){
print(i);
x = read_xlsx(i,sheet=NULL, range=cell_cols("A:AE"), col_names=TRUE, skip=1, trim_ws=TRUE, guess_max=1000)
x$file=i
print(x$file)
 # Return data
 x
})
```

How do I find the count of rows that are read from each excel. I would like to get this number to ensure that I can validate the count of records read with the actual count in the excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize a row-count vector before you call lapply, you could store the number of rows (or full dimensions) of each sheet in that.  Something like:

```
row_counts <- vector()

dat = lapply(file.list, function(i){
    print(i);
    x = read_xlsx(i,sheet=NULL, range=cell_cols("A:AE"), 
        col_names=TRUE, skip=1, 
        trim_ws=TRUE, guess_max=1000)
    row_counts[i] <- nrow(x)
    x$file=i
    print(x$file)
 # Return data
 x
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a `list()` object as the result the apply function, where the output list includes a data object and the count.

Since I have a readily available set of example files in the `csv` format from Alberto Barradas' [Pokémon Stats](https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon) data from kaggle.com, I'll use `read.csv()` instead of `read_xlsx()`, but the process will work for either function.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                              full.names=TRUE)
fileList <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     # read data and generate a list object including the data and row count 
     data <- read.csv(x)
     list(data = data,rows=nrow(data))
})
# extract counts from the list
unlist(lapply(fileList,function(x){x["rows"]}))
```

...and the output:

```
> # extract counts from the list
> unlist(lapply(fileList,function(x){x["rows"]}))
rows rows rows rows rows rows 
 165  106  160  121  165   82 
>
```